# Error converting set statusbarPanel text from VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a code in VB6 as follows:

```
stbStatusBar.Panels("MONITOR").Text = "Monitor Initializing"
```

Now I'm converting code into VB.NET as follows:

```
stbStatusBar.Items.Item("MONITOR").Text = "Monitor Initializing"
```

But it doesn't set any values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does `it doesn't get any values` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is hard to understand code from just one line, I think you forgot to name your Statusbar Panel in designer form in VB.NET.

Check If any panels with name `"SERVER"` exist. If not you should name it as follows:

```
stbStatusBar_Panel.Name = "SERVER"
```

And then add panel in statusbar.

Comment: Yeh ! I missed that... Thanks..